# Meu Expo está preso numa instalação infinita, me ajudem?

Tags: android-studio, react-native, expo

Oii gente, estou tentando configurar o android studio pra poder programar com o react native, porem to com dificuldade em instalar o expo nele, eu já consegui abrir o emulador mas quando vou dar o expo start, ele abre o Metro Bundler e quando eu inicio o Run on Android device/emulator, ele começa a instalar só que não termina nunca.. já deixei quase 40 minutos parado tentando instalar mas não instala.

> C:\Users\Lenovo\instaclone\myapp>expo start Starting project at
> C:\Users\Lenovo\instaclone\myapp Developer tools running on
> http://localhost:19002
> Starting Metro Bundler
> ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄ █ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▄▄▄ ▀▄▀█▄█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █ █ █   █ ██▄▀ █
> ▀▄██ █   █ █ █ █▄▄▄█ ██▀▄ ▄ ██▀█ █▄▄▄█ █ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█ ▀▄█ ▀ ▀ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
> █▄ ▀▄ █▄▀█▄▀█▄██▀ █▄█▀█▀▀▄█ ██▄█▀█▀▄▄█▄██▄█ ▄▀▀███▄▀▀ █ █ ▀▀▄▀▀▄
> █▀█▄ █ ▄▀▀█▀ ██ █ ▄▀▀▄▄▄▀▀█▀█▀▄█ ▄▀ ██▄▀  █ █▄█▄██▄▄█  █ ▄▄ █ ▄▄▄
> ▄▀▄█ █ ▄▄▄▄▄ ██▀ ▀▄  █ █▄█ ███ █ █ █   █ █  █▄ ██▄ ▄  ▄ █▀▀█ █ █▄▄▄█
> █▀    █▄ ▄█▀▀▄█   █ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄█▄██▄▄▄▄█▄▄███▄█
>
> › Metro waiting on exp://192.168.0.42:19000 › Scan the QR code above
> with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)
>
> › Press a │ open Android › Press w │ open web
>
> › Press r │ reload app › Press m │ toggle menu › Press d │ show
> developer tools › shift+d │ toggle auto opening developer tools on
> startup (disabled)
>
> › Press ? │ show all commands
>
> Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit. Started
> Metro Bundler › Opening exp://192.168.0.42:19000 on
>
> This download is taking longer than expected. You can also try
> downloading the clients from the website at https://expo.dev/tools
> Couldn't adb reverse: device 'adb' not found › Opening
> exp://192.168.0.42:19000 on
>
> This download is taking longer than expected. You can also try
> downloading the clients from the website at https://expo.dev/tools 
> Installing Expo Go 2.24.4 on

E então ele não sai desse estado Installing, eu recebo uma mensagem pedindo pra mim tentar baixar os cliente do site citado na penultima linha. Porem eu entrei no site executei os códigos que pediram, não sei se fiz da forma certa mas aparentemente não deu certo. Alguém sabe oq eu posso fazer ?

Answer (score 0):

Eu nunca configurei o expo no android studio, porém, tem duas coisas que sempre to fazendo quando travo assim: é excluir o node-modules e rodar `yarn install e expo r -c`
Outra coisa também, é gerar um novo AVD. Tem AVD que nao funciona. Sugiro também, isntalar o expo num aparelho físico e tentar rodar pelo QR code. Espero que resolva.